# Connecting Form data to MySQL using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, netbeans

I am trying to store the fields from a form in my web-page to a Database in MySQL using JSP. I do not get any errors but i don't see the data in my database when i hit submit. Please help me identify my problem. I have the following codes:

## Sign up - New User

```
        <div id="container">       
        <form action = "insertData.jsp" method = "post">
            <table>
            <tr><td>E-mail/username:</td><td><input type="text" name="e-mail"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date Of Birth:</td><td><input type="text" name="dateOfBirth"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Account Type:</td><td><input type="text" name="type"></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
            </table>           

        </form>    
        </div> 

</body>
```

and my JSP Code

```
<%
    Connection con = null;

    String email = request.getParameter("e-mail");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    String firstName = request.getParameter("fName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lName");
    String dob = request.getParameter("dateOfBirth");

    String accountType = request.getParameter("type");

    String queryText = "insert into user values('" + email + "'+'" + password + "','" + firstName + "','" + lastName + "','" + dob + "','" + accountType + "')";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project", "root", "B@neswor1");

        Statement stat = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rst = stat.executeQuery(queryText);
        System.out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");

        rst.close();
        stat.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    System.out.println("Success");
%>
```

Please help me identify what i am missing

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
    }` - yep no errors being reported

Comment: JSP code should be for display only, move the DB code to a servlet.

Comment: Futhermore, use a preparedStatement or similar for doing your insert.

Comment: You eat the exception, thus no error is shown. Add a e.printStackTrace(); in your catch block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of your problem is your insert query:

```
String queryText = "insert into user values('" + email + "'+'" +
    password + "','" + firstName + "','" + lastName + "','" + dob + "','" +
    accountType + "')";
```

If you look closely, there is no comma after the email literal.  But you could have avoided this by using a prepared statement:

```
String sql = "insert into user values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
ps.setString(1, email);
ps.setString(2, password);
ps.setString(3, firstName);
ps.setString(4, lastName);
ps.setString(5, dob);
ps.setString(6, accountType);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Note that using a statement makes it much easier to see how your query string is being built.  It also frees you from ugly string concatenation and escaping, which is error prone.

@duffymo pointed out many other potential problem with your code, some of which though should not necessarily cause it to crash.  One other problem I see is that your date of birth field is being treated as a string, which it probably should be a date, and you should be inserting into your database as a date.

Comment: and OP, please do not silently swallow your exceptions

Answer (score 1):

There are too many things wrong with this code:

1. Never, ever write scriptlet code in JSPs.
2. You have an empty catch block in that scriptlet code.  If an exception is thrown you'll never know it.
3. Close resources in finally blocks.
4. You don't use PreparedStatement.  You are asking for a SQL injection attack.
5. No XSS check.
6. No validation of input data.
7. Learn JSTL if you must use JSP.
8. Be aware that JSP model is vintage 1998.  Modern UIs are done using HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript talking to REST services. The world has changed in the last 20 years.  Tutorials exist for old technologies, but it doesn't mean they should be your first thought.

Comment: This should be the checklist for anyone posting a JSP/DB question